# Does Android play store allow old version of an app to be downloaded if the new version has higher API?

Tags: android, google-play

Example use case below if anyone needs a specific scenario to understand. But if you already know the answer feel free to share the knowledge.

Previously the app used to support from API 17+. Now it does from 21+. So anyone with API 17 device, can they download the old version?

The app is listed here.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neximolabs.blackr

Ideally it should not support as the latest version is published. But older version of app used to support JB/kitkat. Just need to test how Google play handles this situation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The older version is no longer available. Updates will only be offered to users who have API 21+ on their phones.

Comment: Sounds great. Is there any documentation around it?

Comment: I don't know if there is any documentation, but as a developer I can only have one version of an app available in the play store at any given time. So if I update a new version of my app with minSDK of 21, the older version (minSDK of 17) will no longer be available for my users.